# Drive Picker file upload issue

Tags: google-app-maker

Can anyone shed any light on an issue with the drive picker. The same app

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/drive-picker/

allows select of files but when you try to upload a file you get a "files failed to upload" message (see screenshot)

The app is being run as user so it can't be an identity issue.

Comment: A couple of links to screenshots. the First is the Google app itself, the second is my implementation of a Drive Picker

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Npi8a1KAZhNees-zmXSvjg-mFDdQvUOp

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mhecY966Jqs19I0d0mDBoaRCq6PioaNh

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Drive Picker has “read only” access to a user’s Drive unless your App Maker application specifically requests “read/write” access. So basically in order to use the upload functionality you need to force your App Maker app to request “read/write” access. The easiest way to do this is to create a new ‘Server script’ and add a simple function that would require write access. For example:

```
function writeAccess() {
  DriveApp.addFile();
}
```

This function will never be run or called but App Maker will recognize it needs write access to implement it and request it from the user. So simple add the script file and copy and paste the above. Once write access is available for your application you’ll be able to upload files with Drive Picker.

Comment: Many thanks indeed for that.

This forced the app to re-request permissions and now the upload works fine.